# I stopped an instance after free trial and it got deleted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there any way to recover it? Does google delete instances in this case automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google, as for now, does not offer an ability to recover deleted instances at all. They did receive several feedbacks on this issue (one of them [is here](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/9966057-recover-deleted-instance)) to enable recovering deleted instances or to put deleted instances in a bin for a short period of time, but they leave those ideas "under review" and don't plan to implement it any time soon.